# How to extend the footer to include the margin notes

Tags: header-footer, margins, memoir

My `memoir` document has a relatively narrow typeblock (90mm) and a wide margin (55mm) for annotations, with a `\marginparsep` of 15mm.
I want the footer to cover both the typeblock and the annotation block, so it should be 90+15+55=160mm wide.
When I try to do this with `\makerunningwidth`, the footer is extended in both margins:

```
\documentclass[twoside,a4paper,article]{memoir}
\usepackage{kantlipsum}
\setlrmarginsandblock{30mm}{90mm}{*}
\setmarginnotes{15mm}{55mm}{\onelineskip}
\checkandfixthelayout[nearest]
\typeoutlayout
\makepagestyle{test}
\makerunningwidth{test}{160mm} % typeblock + \marginparsep + \marginparwidth
\makeevenfoot{test}{\thepage}{}{spine}
\makeoddfoot{test}{edge}{}{\thepage}
\pagestyle{test}

\begin{document}
\section{Section heading}
Hello. \marginpar{\kant[40]}\kant[1-5]
\end{document}
```

How can I extend the footer only in the direction of the edge, leaving the spine margin untouched?

Answer (score 9):

You should have a look at the `Ruled` page style in the `memoir` source. You need this:

```
\makeheadposition{test}{flushright}{flushleft}{flushright}{flushleft}
```

Comment: It works, but there seems to be a bug here: the footer always follows the header; you can't handle footers differently from headers; so arguments 4 and 5 don't seem to work.

Comment: You may need the optional argument: `\makerunningwidth{test}[160mm]{90mm}`, as a wild guess, to set the widths for header and footer to different values. Beware of what you wish for, as it may turn out hideous :).

Comment: no, I don't want this for know, the reason for my comment was to report that \makeheadposition can do without its last two arguments - they do nothing. Maybe they should, but then it's a bug.

Comment: The macro is badly named, the last two are for the footers, the first two for the headers

Comment: Sure, I understood so, but the last two don't work.

Comment: You're right, it got lost somewhere. I'll add it to my todo list

Comment: Fixed in the development version